# The Winter of a Hundred Years

Tags: climate

Back home, one ice age during the two and a half million years of the Pleistocene lasted a total of 100,000 years, ninety thousand of intense cold followed by ten thousand of milder interglacial weather.

But in this alternate Earth, we've been in an ice age for five million years, with glaciations lasting 150,000 years followed by interglacials lasting 12,000.  Would a longer Milankovich cycle result in a different climate, a different landscape and a different extent of the ice?

Comment: Well, the Appalachian mountains would be smaller, for one thing.

Comment: There might be a lion, maybe a witch, and also a wardrobe with four children, if you're not careful.

Comment: Will there be any abominable snowman stampede? I think it will be magnificent view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Longer glacial periods would have the effect of scouring more land and pushing the continents down for a longer period of time. The land will take longer to recover from the glacial retreat (creating and laying down soil on the scoured regions, and Isotonic rebound will also be longer), as the continents will have been depressed for a greater period of time. More of the continents will resemble the Canadian Shield, masses of rock covered with a thin layer of poor soil, and more of the land will be low lying and covered in water, either shallow lakes, or later large areas of bogs and swamps (in this region often known as Muskeg).

The effects on the non glaciated regions will also be more extreme, especially as massive meltwater lakes form at the edges of the melting glaciers, eventually breaking through barriers of land and creating gigantic flash floods to scour the lands downstream, or dump billions of litres of cold water into the oceans and interrupt the oceanic currents, creating massive climactic disruptions around the world.

During the long glacial periods, the oceans will be much shallower and the continental shelves will be low lying plains, allowing creatures to move to ranges of hills and mountains, which will rapidly be isolated when the waters rise again, isolating populations of creatures and sparking evolution in isolated populations, creating a rich environment in the offshore islands and coastal regions of the interglacial periods.

So the world in the interglacials will be full of small pocket biomes, but generally poorer in soils and fertile regions in the continental interiors. Late in the period, the isotonic rebound will have uplifted more land and the soils will be replenished, but this will require tens of thousands of years to complete.